# iPhone how can i apply a pdf file as image on a table view cell

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, cell

I am working on a project in which I have to put images on table view cells.
Is it possible to put .pdf format files on table view cells as image?

I used the following code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (!cell)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
  //  NSDictionary *menuAttr = [menuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

      //  cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [menuAttr objectForKey:@"name"]];


    if (indexPath.row ==0 )
    {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"about us.pdf"];

          cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius =cell.imageView.image.size.width/2;
    }
    if (indexPath.row == 3)
    {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"policies.pdf"];
    }
    if (indexPath.row == 2)
    {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"services.pdf"];
    }

       if (indexPath.row == 1)
    {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"home.pdf"];
    }

    if (indexPath.row == 4)
    {
         cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"contact us.pdf"];
    }

    if (indexPath.row == 5)
    {
         cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"feedback.pdf"];
    }

    [tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: in this feedback.pdf place use any common .png

Comment: No. you cannot use a .pdf file for an image. Use an actual image file. Why would you want to put PDF's in cells?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you sure can, but it's only going to give you a shot of the first page of the PDF ... almost like a thumbnail. Here's how you do it:

1. Create an assets folder in Xcode:

[image]

2. Place pdf files into assets catalog:

[image]

3. Change the image so it's the correct format, look on the right side of this picture, you have to change the 5th drop down on the side to "single vector":

[image]

4. Drag image into correct slot, in the previous image you see the yellow warning marker? This happens because the image isn't in the correct slot, you have to drag the PDF file to the slot above to correct this:

[image]

5. you can use this PDF vector file like this:

   ```
   [_window setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"examplepdf"]]];
   ```

I only use vectorized pdfs in my apps. The system resizes these for the correct iphone and ipad sizes by itself, no need to use @2x or @3x or anything else.

Here's an additional tutorial on how this works:

http://martiancraft.com/blog/2014/09/vector-images-xcode6/

You really should FIRST save the PDF files in Illustrator as explained in the tutorial above, but either way, this method should work. Good luck!

Here's the output from the small tutorial I just explained above:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can draw PDFs using CoreGraphics:

1. Open the PDF using `CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL()`.
2. Get the (first or any other) page using `CGPDFDocumentGetPage()`.
3. Draw the page into your own context with `CGContextDrawPDFPage()`.

You need to have the drawing context, so either:

- Create `UIView` subclass, override `-drawRect:` and use it instead of `UIImageView`.
- Setup an image context using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions ()` so you will get an `UIImage` instance.